# Preventing iframe top-level redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I'm trying to prevent a top-level redirect from an iframe. My code works great, but any time a user tries to leave the page, they get asked if they want to stop the script and navigate, or not. This is for a kind of high end website, so I was wondering if there was a way around this dialog box? Here is my current code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return false;
}
```

I'm using sandbox="" in my iframe to prevent the dialog box from poping up onload. If anyone knows how to prevent this from happening upon leaving the page and is willing to give me some advice, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define top-level redirect - are you trying prevent users from leaving the page at all? Preventing redirect from code? Elaborate scenario please.

Comment: I'm feeding in another website (that i don't own) into an iframe. The page I'm feeding in has a top level redirect. My code stop the page from redirecting, but the user is presented with a popup asking if they want to stop the script, in order to leave the page. I just need to get rid of that popup and allow the users to enter and exit freely without having to deal with the popup box.

Comment: Actually, the popup is asking whether or not they want to navigate away from the page. But, this is happening when they are leaving the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually since you already using `sandbox=""` in your IFRAME, it already prevents it from changing top-level location. You can safely remove your `onbeforeunload` event handler.

Note: `sandbox=""` does not work in IE9 and below.

Comment: In firefox this blocks all functionality.